# ExtractValue in mysql is not working for me

Tags: mysql

I have an xml string

```
set @xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SeaTest xsi:schemaLocation="https://sea.retain.hawcik.com/schema    /SeaTestSchema
https://sea.retain.hawcik.com/schema/SeaTestSchema1.0.xsd"     xmlns="https://sea.retain.hawcik.com/schema/SeaTestSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w9.org/2999/XMLSchema-instaccc">
<WorkSourcets>
    <TestWorkSourcets>
        <WorkSourcetsName>SITE01</WorkSourcetsName>
        <SourcetsDetails>
            <DuringssUnits>
                <DuringssUnit>
                    <DuName>TEST.NET</DuName>
                    <SourcetsStatus>REQ</SourcetsStatus>
                    <CompleteTestAsText>TEST.COM,SITE01,11/10/2014</CompleteTestAsText>
                    <MentionedDueDate></MentionedDueDate>
                    <MentionedPriority>Normal</MentionedPriority>
                    <DuSpecificAddtionlyElementtes>
                        <Elementte>
                            <ElementteName>REQUESTEDDATE</ElementteName>
                            <ElementteDataType>DATE</ElementteDataType>
                            <ElementteValue>11/10/2014</ElementteValue>
                        </Elementte>
                    </DuSpecificAddtionlyElementtes>
                </DuringssUnit>
            </DuringssUnits>
        </SourcetsDetails>
    </TestWorkSourcets>
</WorkSourcets>
</SeaTest>';

SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '//DuName');
```

Here i want to get the value from DuName tag TEST.NET. But i don't know why i'm getting null. Please let me know if anything is wrong in the above query.

Comment: Sorry it works could not replicate the issue.

Comment: Now also i tried it returns "NULL" only. How it is working for you

Comment: I set the xml in the cli and then `mysql> SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '//DuName'); 
+--------------------------------+
| ExtractValue(@xml, '//DuName') |
+--------------------------------+
| TEST.NET                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: Thank You !! I'm working in MySQL Workbench.Still not getting the result.

Comment: Try creating a test table and insert the xml into that table field and then use the `extractvalue` on that column and see what happens.

Comment: I have tired that too, but still returning NULL.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (It works for me in the cli.)